# Gas leaking out of a cylinder at constant pressure and volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, gas, inert-gases

[image]The gas is leaking out in such a way so as to maintain the cylinder at a **constant** *pressure* and *volume*, i.e the product of **nT** is constant.

If at a time **t**, the temperature of the gas is **T** and the number of moles remaining is **n**:

$nT = n_{0} T_{0} \implies   d(nT) = 0 \implies T dn = -n dT \\ \implies -\ln{\frac{n}{n_{0}}} = \ln{\frac{T}{T_{0}}}$

Also,
$\frac{dQ}{dt} = Q_{0} \\$ and $dQ = d(\frac{3}{2} nRT)$ since dQ = dU, as work done by gas is zero.

$\\ \implies \frac{d(nT)}{dt} = \frac{2 Q_{0}}{3R} \\\implies n dT + T dn = \frac{2Q_{0} dt}{3R}$

$\implies \int_{T_{0}}^{T} n dT + \int_{n_{0}}^{n} T dn = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{2Q_{0} dt}{3R}$, which upon solving for $\frac{n}{n_{0}}$ and substituting in the first result obtained, produces a quadratic in T.

I fear I may have grossly misunderstood the specific thermodynamic process taking place here despite having given this hours of thought.

Comment: The options are all in the form of $T_{0} e^{f(t)}$, hence the apprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics tells us that $$dU=d(nu)=dQ+(u+Pv)dn=dQ+(u+RT)dn$$or$$ndu=dQ+RTdn$$Substituting du=C_VdT gives:  $$nC_vdT=dQ+RTdn$$Since nT=Const,we then have $$nC_pdT=dQ$$or$$n_0C_pT_0d\ln(T)=dQ$$and $$Q=n_0C_pT_0\ln{(T/T_0)}$$

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't studied open systems, and reading any online literature on this topic isn't helping me gauge the meaning of your variables. Could you kindly define them at the very start?

Comment: Sorry.  Application of the open system (control volume) version of the 1st law of thermodynamics was the only way I could think of to solve this problem (sine mass and energy are leaving the system).

Comment: yes I understand, but it's just that I don't understand what your variables mean. Could you elaborate only on the first line, really only the first 3 expressions, I understand the remainder of your post full well and managed to derive the answer in its complete form.

Comment: I take it that dU is the change in internal energy of the system, but the "d(nu) = dQ + (u + Pv)dn" confuses me. I suppose it's the mathematical interpretation of the fact that change internal energy of the system = $W_{in} - W_{out}+ E_{in} - E_{out} + M_{in} - M_{out}$, but I fail to interpret the variables.

Comment: You need to read up on the derivation of the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics, particularly the resolution of the total work into 2 separate parts:  work to push fluid into- and out of the control volume,  and "shaft work."